# python pymp4 failed to get box type

Tags: python, mp4

I am trying to edit the box data of some mp4 files to do so i am looking at using the pymp4 option in python how ever i seem to be running into an issue just trying to detect the box type as it throws and error

there does not seem to be a lot of documentation around pymp4 even on google so any help would be amazing below is the code i am using now that results in an error : "str does not have type"

```
boxes = Box.parse_stream(io.BytesIO(data))
for box in boxes:
    if box.type == b"senc":
        print("found")
```

Answer (score 0):

`parse_stream` will yield each `Box` it finds, so you need to keep calling it until you find the box you want:

```
    stream = io.BytesIO(data)
    stream.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
    eof = stream.tell()
    stream.seek(0)

    while stream.tell() < eof:
        box = Box.parse_stream(stream)
        if box.type == b"senc":
            print("found")
```

Obviously this assumes the input is well-formed etc - you should probably do some error-checking and such.

Adapted from an example in the source, available at https://github.com/beardypig/pymp4/blob/427f232beb326c07a1035d7bd8ff6e05049b76e9/src/pymp4/cli.py